# Temp space behaviour when oracle query called form Java Persistence

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

The problem is when i run query from Pl/sql developer its giving result, But when i am running query from my java application it will give following error.

```
08:46:49,106 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-3) SQL Error: 1652, SQLState: 72000
08:46:49,107 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-3) ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP
```

So Is there any behavior change for allocating temp memory when i called from the java application.

Thanks

Comment: and what operation is being performed?

Comment: In query sorting is done. And ROW_NUMBER() and TO_CHAR() function as well.

Comment: any reason why the actual query cannot be posted? so people don't have to guess

Answer (score 1):

This could be related to the operation you are attempting. The [temporary tablespace](http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/temporary_tablespaces.htm) is used for various operations (sorting, etc.). More info is available [in the Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/physical.htm#CNCPT1103).

In such a case you have two solutions:

1. Find a workaround for the operation exceeding the temporary tablespace size
2. Contact your DBA and ask him to increase the tablespace size - or any architecture modification to solve your problem (you should have serious reasons for that)

Meanwhile the error you get is not exactly a problem of space, but rather a problem in the allocation of memory. Some [specific situation of the database](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_reclaim_space_temp_segment.htm) could also be the origin of the Oracle code. Only your DBA could check the situation. It would be wise to make sure your operation is valid before contacting your DBA.